# what is a fiber for function mapping?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, definition

I have read that a fiber is the pre image of a mapping..

Does this mean that I can think of a fiber as a line that connects x to y where the line is a function?

So for example with $f(x)=2x$ there is a line going from $x$ to $2x$ for all $x$ and these are all the fibers? Is that right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fiber of, say, $y=1$ is the set of all $x$ such that $f(x)=1$.
For your example, $f(x)=2x$, the fiber of $1$ is the set $\left\{\dfrac12\right\}$, 
the fiber of $8$ is $\{4\}$, etc.

More interesting examples when the function is not 1-1, like take $g(x)=x^2$. Then the fiber of $4$ is $\{-2,2\}$, the fiber of $16$ is $\{-4,4\}$.

You use the word pre-image: The pre-image (or fiber) of *a point* $y$ is the set $f^{-1}(y):=\{x:f(x)=y\}$.

Comment: so i can think of a fiber as a set of lines going from some $y$ to all of the $x$ that the function can take there?

so $f(x)=\sin(x)$ has $y=1$ having fiber lines going from $y=1$ to all $x=2n\pi+\frac{\pi}2$ (assuming i did the trignometrics right)

Comment: You could do this if that helps, think of a fiber as a set of lines  (or a set of arrows) that go from $y$ back to all the $x$'s, though formally these arrows are not really a mathematical object (in this context) and the fiber is the set of points where these lines end (on the $x$'s side). The lines do help to visualize the fiber, even if they are not the fiber themselves. The fiber is a set of $x$'s from the domain of the function.

Comment: thank you. so a fiber is just all x in domain of mapping for a single y after the mapping. all x that yield that specific y. i get it now

Comment: Yes, and I believe that the word fiber is used specifically when we talk about the pre-image of a single point $y$ (as opposed to the pre-image of a set of $y$'s).

Comment: yeah i think you are right. thank you so much mirko!